# Only the user can enter the program, but other users cant enter the program

Tags: python, function, authentication, taskmanager

I have made changes to my code so that the program runs through the whole file containing the usernames and passwords for the program, but I get feedback that only the username 'admin' can have access to the program, and not other users.

Is there another way where the program can maybe run through the whole file and see if the username entered is the same as the username in the file?

My code is as follows:

def login():

```
username = input("Enter your username: ")
password = input("Enter your password: ")

for line in open('user.txt', 'r').readlines():
    field = line.strip().split(", ")
    if username == field[0] and password == field[1]:
        print('Welcome' + username)
        return True, field[0] == "admin"

    return False, False
```

login_success, is_admin = login()

if login_success and is_admin:
display_admin_menu_options()
elif login_success:
display_menu_options()
else:
print("Username or password incorrect!")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outer return statement is inside the for-loop. Try:

```
def login():
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")

    for line in open('user.txt', 'r').readlines():
        field = line.strip().split(", ")
        if username == field[0] and password == field[1]:
            print('Welcome' + username)
            return True, field[0] == "admin"

    return False, False
```

My guess is that `admin` is at the top of `user.txt` file. So as soon as you input the admin password and username, it matches the fields and you return `True,True`. But if you input something else, it skips the if statement and returns `False,False`. You never loop more than once because your return statement always terminates the program in the first loop.

Comment: Yes, the username 'admin' is at the top of the txt file, but when I register myself as a user and use my name and password, the code completely crashes and doesn't display the menu options for the user

Comment: @WesleyBokBooyzen Have you tried changing the `login()` function according to my suggestion? And in that case, do you still get the error? My suggestion is basically to unindent the `return False,False` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! Appreciate the help.